# No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Guid' and 'System.String'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, type-conversion, expression-trees

I am building Expression tree for `Linq-to-sql`. In database on some of tables relevant columns are stored as `string` while some are stored as `Guid`. I have solved similar problem with `int` and `int?` by wrapping lambda constant with `Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.PolicyNumber), policyNumberColumnLambda.Type)` (where `PolicyNumber` sometimes was `nullable`)  which worked just fine. But it does not fly for `Guid` to `string` conversion apparently.

**Code looks following:**

```
public static IQueryable<IRetrieveGuid> SearchByRetrieveGuid<IRetrieveGuid>(this IQueryable<IRetrieveGuid> queryable, SearchModel search)
    {
        var paramLambda = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IRetrieveGuid));
        var columnLambda = Expression.Property(paramLambda, "retrieveguid");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IRetrieveGuid, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(columnLambda, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.RetrieveGuid), columnLambda.Type)), paramLambda);
        return queryable.Where(lambda);
    }
```

**How do I convert types to match in expression tree?**

Comment: So the database column is a guid?  Why not just pull it in as a quid and convert to string in linq-to-objects?

Comment: @DStanley in some tables it's GUID while in some it's string. I am writing sorta aspect oriented thing via interfaces to query massive disorganized databases (MSSQL and Oracle), and interfaces that I am putting on are `Interface<t> { T Property}` so I don't know type beforehand (this might explain it :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812584/putting-interface-behind-properties-with-same-name-but-different-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION1:**

This is by a magnitude faster than solution2, however if you have variety of possibilities might result in long `if else` or `switch` statement

```
var retrieveGuidAsString =  search.RetrieveGuid.ToString();
var constantLambda = columnLambda.Type.Name == "Guid"  ? Expression.Constant(search.RetrieveGuid) : Expression.Constant(retrieveGuidAsString);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IRetrieveGuid, bool>>(Expression.Equal(columnLambda, constantLambda), paramLambda);
```

**SOLUTION2:**

[This did work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862314/linq-expression-conversion-concat-from-int-to-string#answer-17862987)

```
public static IQueryable<IRetrieveGuid> SearchByRetrieveGuid<IRetrieveGuid>(this IQueryable<IRetrieveGuid> queryable, SearchModel search)
    {
        var paramLambda = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IRetrieveGuid));
        var columnLambda = Expression.Property(paramLambda, "retrieveguid");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IRetrieveGuid, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(columnLambda, Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.RetrieveGuid), typeof (object)), typeof (object).GetMethod("ToString"))), paramLambda);
        return queryable.Where(lambda);
    }
```

but is incredibly slow as it produces following sql

`([Extent1].[retrieveguid] = 'c87d1234-46ad-47bf-9a9c-d9a35a454bd5' as uniqueidentifier) AS nvarchar(max))))) OR (([Extent1].[retrieveguid] IS NULL) AND (LOWER( CAST( cast('c87d1234-46ad-47bf-9a9c-d9a35a454bd5' as uniqueidentifier) AS nvarchar(max))) IS NULL)))`